# Given an unknown primitive type array in the form of an object, convert it to double array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, primitive-types

I have searched previous questions here, but nothing quite answers exactly what I am looking for.

I am retrieving an array of primitive type via reflection using PropertyInfo in the form of type object.

```
    Type t = typeof(MyType);    
    PropertyInfo pi = t.GetProperty("Property Name");

    object primitiveTypeArray = pi.GetValue(myObject)

    double[] convertedArray = (double[])primitiveTypeArray;
```

There are only 3 type this array can be (for now), double, float or ulong.
This assignment of convertedArray will only work if the primitiveTypeArray object contains a double[], but fails if it is a float[] of ulong[].

I have found the Array class and Convert class have some helper functions that might assist, but I am having trouble understanding how to appropriately use them to solve this problem.

Thank you

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.UInt64[]' to type 'System.Double[]'.' and if I attempt to cast a float, it throws System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Single[]' to type 'System.Double[]'.'

Comment: As a `double` cannot represent all possible values of an `ulong`, and converting from `float` yields values that have apparent higher precision when they're converted to a decimal representation (though no bits are lost), keep in mind that such conversions are potentially lossy. Depending on what you're planning to do with the data you may just want three separate paths for computation.

Comment: Very good point and thank you for bringing that consideration up. Hopefully everything should be fine as the ulong values are truncated and represent millions, so the limit of a double should never be reached with the given context of the applicatoin, but it does show some checks need to be made before assignement

Comment: Does it need to be a `double`? In .NET 7 they introduced the `INumber` interface which you could use here. If you do actually need a `double`, use `Convert.ChangeType<double[]>(input)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have just `3` types, why not to check all these possibilities?

```
using System.Linq;

...

object primitiveTypeArray = pi.GetValue(myObject)

double[] convertedArray = 
    primitiveTypeArray is double[] da ? da
  : primitiveTypeArray is float[] fa ? fa.Select(item => (double) item).ToArray()
  : primitiveTypeArray is ulong[] ua ? ua.Select(item => (double) item).ToArray()
  : null; // or throw exception here
```

Please, note that we can't just cast `float[]` into `double[]` but can create required `double[]`.

Comment: Thank you, this has solved my problem. I think I was attempting to make it as streamlined as possible with a single statement like what Ahmed Alayat suggested, but even that was throwing exceptions.